# Seeding database with path from code?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I've been using Laravel's migrations with the path parameter like so:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'path/to/my/Migrations'));
```

Is there anyway I can run the seed command in the same way?  I have a number of seed files I want to use but I don't want to run them all at the same time.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Instead of --path you can set --class with namespace to Seeder class.

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
    '--class' => 'Namespace\Seeds\DatabaseSeeder'
]);
```

This works on Laravel 5.1

Comment: A cleaner way

`Artisan::call('db:seed', [ '--class' => DatabaseSeeder::class, ]);`

Answer (score 2):

To refresh the migrations and seed the database, this worked for me:

```
// Roll back all migrations and migrate them again
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
// Fill tables with seeds
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

I had lots of seeds and the server was slow. In this case it helps to extend the maximum execution time.

```
// Extend maximum execution time to 3 minutes
set_time_limit(180);
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
Artisan::call('db:seed');
// Back to the default
set_time_limit(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeding only

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

Re-run all migration under specified path & run seeds as well

```
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', array('--path' => 'path/to/my/Migrations', '--seed'));
```

Comment: Hi, when using the second command, I get the following error: The "--path" option does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use syntax below and take advantage of type checking

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
    '--class' => UserSeeder::class
]);
```