# Clone database or run sql dump on the fly in laravel 4

Tags: database, laravel-4, mysql

I have a big project in laravel 4, and i need to make new database with lot of tables on the fly. I can make empty database on the fly, but how to fill it up with tables? I cant use migrations on the fly, because this application have lot of permissions, so user cant pass them.

First option is to clone empty database (empty from data but with tables).
Second option is run sql dump file on the fly.

Can someone explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides an option to fill the database through seeding . check the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) .

> Laravel also includes a simple way to seed your database with test
>   data using seed classes. All seed classes are stored in
>   app/database/seeds. Seed classes may have any name you wish, but
>   probably should follow some sensible convention, such as
>   UserTableSeeder, etc. By default, a DatabaseSeeder class is defined
>   for you. From this class, you may use the call method to run other
>   seed classes, allowing you to control the seeding order.

after defining the seed class . you can seed the database through the command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

---

check this [blog post](http://culttt.com/2013/12/16/seeding-laravel-4-database/) on how to use seeing and also [faker library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to prefill databased with real like test data.

if you can't use command line. you can call the seed command from your code . check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701314/seeding-database-with-path-from-code) .

Comment: I cant use artisan on the fly, because it is on another server and there users hasnt got permissions. I need to clone db on the fly without comand line comands

Comment: @user3921996 then i guess importing the sql dump file be your option .

Comment: @user3921996 you can call artisan seed from the code `Artisan::call('db:seed');`

Comment: sql dump is onption, but how to do that in code? I cant find any information about that

Comment: @user3921996 check my second comment and update to anser

Comment: @user3921996 seed command can only fill databases with values, if you want to create databases, you need migrations . again you call migrations with `Artisan::call('db:migrate')`

Comment: A cant use migrations. I have two options, database clone and sql dump. Thats all.

Comment: @user3921996 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php